# order and limit on a select query zend framework 2

Tags: mysql, select, zend-framework2

Earlier this day a asked a question about an update query. But now i want to select some things ( and it is working ) but I also want to order them and put a limit on it.

This is the code to select all the food :

```
public function getFood($id)
{
    $id = (int)$id;

    $rowset = $this->tableGateway->select(array('kindOfFood_id' => $id));

    $row = $rowset->current();

    if (!$row) {
        throw new \Exception("Could not find row $id");
    }
    return $row;
}
```

But how can i do this :

Select * from KindOfFood  **==> order by kindOfFood_votes DESC ?**

I saw on the documentation you can do something like this, but it doesn't work with me?

```
$rowset = $artistTable->select(function (Select $select) {
     $select->where->like('name', 'Brit%');
     $select->order('name ASC')->limit(2);
});
```

Comment: If you need only `Select * from KindOfFood ==> order by kindOfFood_votes DESC` then remove the `$select->where('kindOfFood_id = ' . $id);` line from the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking to return only single row or multiple rows.

Try this for multiple rows -

```
use Zend\Db\Sql\Select; //at the top of the page among other use statements.

public function getFood($id)
{
    $id = (int) $id;

    $select = new Select(TABLE_NAME);       //CHANGE TABLE_NAME as per needs
    $select->where('kindOfFood_id = ' . $id);
    $select->order('kindOfFood_votes DESC');

    $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->selectWith($select);  //Will get array of rows.

    //$row = $rowset->current(); THIS IS FOR RETURNING ONLY SINGLE ROW NOT ALL ROWS

    if (!$resultSet) {
        throw new \Exception("Could not find rows with food id - $id");
    }
    return $resultSet;
```

}

Can access the returned resultSet via loop. Eg: foreach

```
foreach($resultSet as $row) {
    echo $row->kindOfFood_id;   //or something
}
```

**Note:**

If you need only

`Select * from KindOfFood order by kindOfFood_votes DESC`

then remove the `$select->where('kindOfFood_id = ' . $id);` line from above.